# dynamic_cast type checking functionality without the cast?

Tags: c++, rtti, dynamic-cast

There are a lot of question on the subject, but none seem to address this specifically: Given a code base that does not allow everything solved with virtual functions (as you would do normally) there is a function:

```
/** Check if obj is a T, including base classes. */
template <class T>
inline bool is_a(const basic &obj)
{
    return dynamic_cast<const T *>(&obj) != 0;
}
```

But obviously the cast is made even if unnecessary. How to write this function to check only, i.e., using the `dynamic_cast` functionality without doing the actual cast? Assume that it is impractical to replace calls to this function with virtual functions, or to implement a poor man's RTTI for the purpose.

EDIT: added question mark to title emphasizing the doubt about the possibility

Comment: I'm not sure you'd gain anything measurable. Complexity's in the checking.

Comment: Without virtual functions, dynamic casting doesn't work either, so I really wonder what your codebase looks like. Also, I don't see how virtual functions could help here, apart from making dynamic casting work.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : a misunderstanding, of course there are virtual functions but the check is needed nevertheless.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you want to use a function without using the function. Why are you trying to avoid `dynamic_cast()`?

Comment: What is the *difference* between what you want and what `dynamic_cast` does?

Comment: I thought the title said it. How to improve the title in your opinion?

Comment: I think I understand your question, you only want to perform the necessary parts of the type check but without the possibly required pointer adjustments. I don't see a way to do that, the closest would be using the Visitor Pattern, but that requires virtual functions. "including base classes" should be "including public base classes", btw.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : that sounds like an answer, can you please give a link to the usage of Visitor for that purpose?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%2B%2B+Visitor+Pattern

Comment: What will you do with the check? OK suppose you have managed to check that your GenericWidgetPtr actually points to a SpecificGadget object. Now what?

Comment: Do you really only want to find out, if `basic` is derived from `T` (this is what "is_a" usually implies)? `dynamic_cast` is usually used to cast into the other direction. Also I don't see a reason, why you would need to take an object in the first place to answer this question.

Comment: Or do you want to check if the runntime type of `obj`is in any way related to `T` (so `T` could inherit from base or vice versa) which is what your code checks for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the actual cast is just adding an offset to the pointer. Any steps needed to determine that offset are also needed to determine whether the cast is possible at all. And a good optimizer will optimize out that final addition anyway, as adding a constant to a non-null pointer that is not used except for a null test does not have an effect.

Therefore any replacement that doesn't improve the design would have no measurable effect; the correct replacement if a better design is not possible for some reason is therefore to leave the function as it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent functionality. You've only got two alternatives.

1. Start hand-rolling RTTI (the worst option) including visitors.
2. Just keep using dynamic_cast.

I don't know why you even care about preventing the pointer adjustment, because it's a fairly trivial case of a couple of vtable lookups (into vtables that are already in cache) and performing a couple of subtractions. All of the actual work of `dynamic_cast` would be done in both cases. Furthermore, I don't see what use the result of `is_a` would be without casting the pointer to that type.

There is no easy way to do what you want, principally because it doesn't really make sense and therefore nobody decided to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast()` will also fail if the base class is not polymorphic , meaning it doesn't have any virtual methods. meaning that B may inherit from A, but `dynamic_cast()` on B* to A* will fail because A doesn't have any virtual function .

luckily , we have C++11 : `std::is_base_of<>` : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

which works even if A and B aren't polymorphic , and it also works on compile time, meaning no run-time overhead

Example :

```
class A {};
class B : public A{};

int main (){
B b;
if (std::is_base_of<A,decltype(b)>::value){
   std::cout<<"b can be up-cast to A*";
}
return 0;
}
```

(can be viewed in : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5612738047ff3a5)

make sure to remove any reference or pointer beforehand with `std::remove_pointer` and `std::remove_reference` if dealing with with them

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand the question, but how does `std::is_base_of` help to find the runtime type of an object? Ususally you use dynamic cast to cast a base pointer that actually pointes to a derived object. In the other direction you can just use static cast.

Comment: as far as I understand the question , the OP asked how can one know if some object from A class inherits from B class, but without using dynamic_cast, or any cast - since it's a very expensive operation. now , using decltype() and is_base_of one can know either A inherits from B and vice-versa without runtime-overhead or casting. I might be wrong and the OP asked completly different question. let's see what does he response

Comment: That would at least explain, why obj is taken by reference. In this case however. your statement `dynamic_cast() will also fail if [...] it doesn't have any virtual methods.` is wrong. I belive the compiler can detect a dynamic up_cast at compile time and convert it into a static cast, so I really doubt, there is any efficiency gaine here (although your solution is much clearer/better)

Comment: I agree that one doesn't need to turn the world around just to save some millisecond of dynamic_cast. so I agree with the other answer that maybe the solution is not to solve in the first place. anyway, I stick to the standard. I can't assume what the compiler will do or not or give compiler-based answer here.

Comment: Where in the standard does it say that `dynamic_cast` will fail in that case? The requirement about `basic` having to be a `polymorphic type` exists only for downcasts, but you are checking for the possibility of an upcast (at least as far as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is concerned).

Comment: I've checked with three compilers (g++-4.9, clang++-3.5 and VS2013) and all of them allow upcasts of non polymorphic types via `dynamic_cast`, so I'd really be suprised, if the standard says otherwise.